# UITextView not resizing within UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview

I have a `UIView` that has three subviews, two buttons and one text view. One button is constrained to the left and bottom of the `UIView` and the other is constrained to the right and bottom. The text view is constrained to the top and bottom of the `UIView` as well as the two buttons.

I resize the `UIView` when the text view changes the size. I do the logic within `textViewDidChange` function

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    var messageViewHeight = messageView.frame.height
    var messageY = messageView.frame.origin.y
    // Resize the message view if text view has multiple lines
    if (textView.contentSize.height > messageViewHeight) {
        messageViewHeight += origHeight
        messageY -= origHeight
    }
    // Set the message view frame
    messageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: messageY, width: messageView.frame.size.width, height: messageViewHeight)
}
```

Where `origHeight` is the original height of the `UITextView` and `messageView` is the parent `UIView`.

The `UIView` gets resized properly, but the problem is that the text view doesn't get resized. I don't have enough reputation to post images yet to show the screenshot.

It appears all the subviews aren't constrained to the bottom of the `UIView` any longer. Do I need to add the constraints again? Or is there a better way on resizing the `UIView`?

Comment: Have you tried `messageView.bounds = CGRectMake(.....)`

Comment: Changing the bounds doesn't help. It is my understanding that bounds is where the view is allowed to draw. This doesn't get changed when we modify the frame does it?

Comment: @MikeWalker you can try upload an image to some image hosting services such as imgur.com